# WebElement reordering using drag & drop in same destination

Tags: java, selenium

> **Scenario**: Perform element reordering by drag & drop.

Multiple elements(`<tr> -- draggable`) exists under same `<table>`
For reordering I need to drag the second element `table tr:nth-child(2)` and drop it over the first tr.

[image]

I am not able to do this.

Code written till now:

```
@FindBy(id = "#GridView_pptasks")
protected WebElement reorderDestination;

@FindBy(css = "#GridView_pptasks > tbody > tr:nth-child(2)")
protected WebElement reorderElement;

-------------------------------------------------------------------

Actions act = new Actions(driver);
act.dragAndDrop(reorderElement, reorderDestination).build().perform();
```

Answer (score 0):

Use below code:

```
Actions action= new Actions(driver);
action.clickAndHold(reorderElement).build().perform();
Thread.sleep(2000);
action.clickAndHold().moveToElement(reorderDestination).release(reorderDestination).build().perform();
```

Answer (score 0):

If this is implemented with HTML 5 Drag and Drop, you will not be able to automate with Selenium.  It is a known issue that Selenium does not support this.

However, you can use Javascript execution to get around this issue; http://elementalselenium.com/tips/39-drag-and-drop

Normally I am very much against Javascript Execution when using Selenium to test applications, but in this case there is no other choice

Comment: Is there same implementation available in Java?